# Using the "Alternative Pattern" Mixin in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mixins

I don't understand TypeScript's article on [Alternative Pattern](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern) for mixins.  I see that when I execute the code as they have on the website, I get the methods mixed in, but I don't get properties.  e.g. [this example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEGEHsBMFNQMaQA4EtbVAMwE6QLagAWALicgM4BcIA7vQHQkCeysFCOqyJANgIYA7AOYNIOYcGiQEFYESHQARpEgBrYPlQAPVIIoNS%20XgGJ%20vErByD%20JVADdYAWmS3L1gLAAobyFABRfgQiUC1dQVBUClB%20UBIcfmhUO0gbXgCAZUQBCgpvBBzogCkAV3xXJV54AG9vUFAAL1AAXlAARgBuOtAAKzLkAAoASlBarwBIJH1IKoZeSGEBgHJS8owloa6veoBfbz2fLz8ASUECkqSROKJ4JX4KWHzC0AzkLktR7u0W0AAGLfqzB%20-323l8YAAKjcIsxICVEDhYLZ4EJIoJ3FggvBaERUMFQlZhOxwdd4LBtGwEJZMGE9NFaMkQiQbqAKPx8PAbByYtFYSUcKA7g9vHoMViXm9kmTtJZBNBiv1%20JUagc-ABBZDIXhA5nwWn6NEkSCkwX3eAFe7Reyofgk3WgIpZWygHAldGoDnefia7UAWR0dIGr3esAANKAANqrCpVAC6mzBXiqJFAWv4zCsP0EsFoEpDwy2UwoM1gcwWAzTGZwDAaCcOfihUUQqN4DhRgmYOKs8D0oD5AqQcCFsCo3iwbqpqFSMR9zH94QoAzgXEc0HARpwVBiHfDRfiJSp4mo2%20YEfjn22iFSFH3h5wBiw4kCwQGA2H6-EI2aAD4L-V6gA8koPSwFSDBEiQAG0IIAAKeBsDgLAAHLsuwb5mh%201ZvJARosGwQwMI%20ODPkQr5crAX6-mM-7-kBIFgXAWB6LAcEoFYLADN0NH1MubZrhuDDYbhrBhlx3HkaGYk0XRoEkOBsCQdBrEISwAAi7CcNwG7oQ8mGCXgwlsOG5EjAAPqZUncTJYGcEilgDIIJS8LwQyWXWNE7O5oCeVsOxAA)

I added the property `z = 1;` to `Jumpable`, create my class, and console.log z, but the value is `undefined`.  If instead I used the [Constrained Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins) pattern, it works as expected, but I don't particularly care for how that looks and was hoping that I'm doing something wrong with the Alternative Pattern.  Does anyone have any guidance?

Code for reference:

```
// Code copied from https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern

// Each mixin is a traditional ES class
class Jumpable {
  z = 1;
  jump() {
    console.log('Jumped');
  }
}

// Including the base
class Sprite {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
}

// Then you create an interface which merges
// the expected mixins with the same name as your base
interface Sprite extends Jumpable {}
// Apply the mixins into the base class via
// the JS at runtime
applyMixins(Sprite, [Jumpable]);

let player = new Sprite();
console.log(player.z);

// This can live anywhere in your codebase:
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, constructors: any[]) {
  constructors.forEach((baseCtor) => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach((name) => {
      Object.defineProperty(
        derivedCtor.prototype,
        name,
        Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(baseCtor.prototype, name) ||
          Object.create(null)
      );
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: In my opinion the biggest design flaw is the (mis)use of classes as mixins. Classes are perfect for instantiation, inherited properties/behavior and subtyping. They are not best suited for pure (mixin based) composition tasks. There are better alternatives for (de)structuring code into composable units of reuse.

Comment: Answer ... the provided code and especially the implementation of `applyMixins` clearly shows that at no point a (necessary super) `Jumpable` call is involved. Everything is just about copying properties from one prototype to another. Thus one achieves gluing together prototypal behavior but not the composition of properties which materialize just at instantiation/call time. For the OP's particular use case one was better off with a `Jumper` class and `class Sprite extends Jumper { /* ... */}`.

Comment: Conclusion ... The *Alternative Pattern* works very well as long as one just wants to copy *class* specific behavior from one constructor's prototype to another constructor's prototype.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, feel free to post that as an answer, so I can upvote you properly.  Thank you for the response though!

Comment: it's ok like it is now; I will upvote your research effort instead and Bergi's answer since it is more comprehensive and also does provide example code.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern does not take property initialisation into account, i.e. it ignores the constructors of the mixins. This is why mixins should not have `constructor`s at all, and ideally not use `class` syntax. (Notice that `z = 1;` is not a class property, it's syntactic sugar to create a `.z` instance property in the constructor).

To use this pattern, provide a mixin-specific initialisation method instead:

```
class Jumpable {
  z: number;
  initJumpable() {
    this.z = 1;
  }
  jump() {
    console.log('Jumped');
  }
}

class Sprite {
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  constructor() {
    this.initJumpable()
  }
}

interface Sprite extends Jumpable {}

applyMixins(Sprite, [Jumpable]);
```

Comment: So you're saying still use the `applyMixins` method as well as the init method you provided?  If so, do you recommend the Constrained Mixins?  Because they still use classes

Comment: @incutonez ... 1/2 ... Deside yourself by answering e.g. the question which will be asked in the very end. From the [*Alternative Pattern*'s provided example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#alternative-pattern) and executing `interface Sprite extends Jumpable, Duckable {}`, `applyMixins(Sprite, [Jumpable, Duckable]);` and `let player = new Sprite();` what do you expect `Object.getPrototypeOf(player)` to be? And how about `applyMixins(Sprite, [Duckable, Jumpable]);`? What is the prototype in the latter case?.. *first:* `Duckable`, *last:* `Jumpable` ...

Comment: @incutonez ... 2/2 ... From a mixin I personally don't expect either. In my opinion any mixin approach might change whichever kind of object including the `prototype` but it should never alter the prototype chain itself; thats exclusive to inheritance. Now the question. Can you personally or the project live with this kind of mixin implementation which is based on a crippled form of inheritance but tries to obfuscate this fact?

Comment: @incutonez Yes, this approach would still call `applyMixins`, to get the `initJumpable` method onto `Sprite.prototype`. Sorry if that wasn't clear - edited. Whether this pattern is a *good* approach I cannot say.

Comment: @incutonez Personally I would prefer `class Sprite extends mixins(Duckable, Jumpable) { … }` or `class Sprite implements Duckable, Jumpable { constructor() { mixinDuckable(this); mixinJumpable(this); } … }` but I've never really used mixins myself (in TypeScript).

Comment: @PeterSeliger, it's hard for me to answer because I'm much newer to how JS/TS does things... I come from using [Ext JS Mixins](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.3.1/classic/Ext.Class.html#cfg-mixins), which felt the most natural to me, so coming up with a system to emulate that would be ideal... I'm still mulling all of this over, but I appreciate you adding color and asking the probing questions.

Comment: @incutonez ... The concept of ExtJs mixins just proves that a good implementation does not need to be opinionated. The nice thing here is the `mixin` slot one always can fall back to in case of being in need of resolving composition conflicts explicitly. Btw ...it is not complicated at all and even advisable to come up with an own mixin implementation which fits the developers' / project's / company's need best in terms of DRY and composable code-reuse. If not everyone of your team wants to or can wrap one's head around the class/interface based JS/TS way, there is no need to follow this path.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, I think Ext JS made me very opinionated, and I have high standards for what a framework should provide to the dev... unfortunately, this notion has changed quite a bit with the modularization that's gone on with newer frameworks.  It's unfortunate because I'm having to figure out from the ground level what all is needed... not necessarily a bad thing, but it's like having to relearn how to ride a bike.  I appreciate your comments though... I think I've got an idea of how I want to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, as of 5/19/2021, it seems like mixins are not well-supported in JS/TS ([Bryntum](https://www.bryntum.com/blog/the-mixin-pattern-in-typescript-all-you-need-to-know-part-2/) seems to agree).  There's the [ts-mixer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-mixer) package which should most likely solve my problem, but I first decided to implement using [Constrained Mixins](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/mixins.html#constrained-mixins).  This route seems decent, except I don't think generics work well ([Fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PQKhCgAIUgFBTATpALgC3pAJgewMYDOANKhpAEbwA2OA7pAOIDCOAdgSogK54o7IBLApFpoAhihGYCaHFypYKmLgQGsA5iXJdJASUjr4ksZDw4AtgAcBVTEkT8oMAGYPzkeASpqUJAjkh9LCExcltSTG5w535IAAEUAE9LTzxEAUsUAFpPb1YUYHIxViyklOEAbwBfJ0gAZXhMMSp-AC5INBQUSwJW4GB1AXQucgA6M3NgMtT0zJyvHynkmYzs3MWhAi5PYAAmAAYANgBmAGJN7YnzeHysw4B2AFYARkfDgBYATl2nYHBpxgsdicHh8RAAHgAKpAALyQaoAPlhkFY8HoAApRlixIh1L1IMVEgBtAC6AEpYUjIQBucDgZxcVi8ARsSAAKS4VlCtihHgAHigblhhMw2BxuLx%20Aj0UN4OZ2pCKRUoJBVYgjFxEKxTFQxARhPABULhLL3MrVRaLQAvZG7Wkqy2qszAiVgzFY53OATqdqE0lKh2Oy1bFKIdFk2lBoPoISjG1wz3eon7ElxyNRmqWmo1cB4XX6%20qWdKCqFIw2C1jC9mcyzc%20DogCCiEQYkSActfORz3tlud4tB-HRiZ9BNYbfhgeDXFDQ7YXvUEcD2bpfckbEwcNR9DqRdl6PN1vaux%20VUXfZwtlGNHU6PXcYjQA))... although, I could be totally doing something wrong.  There was also the issue of trying to use `{}` as a type, and the eslint parser throwing a tantrum, but per [this thread](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492), it seems like disabling the rule is fine.  All in all, this gets the job done, and I'm able to contain it in its own file, so I'm happy with this solution.

Comment: *"... it seems like mixins are not well-supported in JS/TS ..."* ... nitpicking ... mixins / traits / [talents](http://scg.unibe.ch/research/bifrost/talents) are natural to JS in many ways / flavors / schools ... the concept gets screwed by any approach which oppressively tries pressing it into classes.

Comment: That's fair, and I guess what I'm probably asking is more of multiple inheritance, at least with the desire to classify them... I have more of a problem with how mixins look.  Defining a class is much cleaner.